# angularjs ng-grid cellTemplate file-referenced on .Net MVC

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

anybody fights with a rebellious html file?

i.e. how to reference a file on ng-grid columnsDef CellTemplate .Net MVC directory structure? I have followed ng-grid site examples but I hadn't be able to make it work. If I put html code inside js file it works fine.

I'm trying to put the file everywhere but it doesn't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will respond to myself.

After looking for cellTemplate inside ng-grid.js I saw that it was called to a get ajax function, then I thought that what I was needing was an Action in my MVC Controller that response the partial view I needed.

In cellTemplate property of my angular controller I only put the call to MVC Controller and 'voilà'... It works!!!